# Get public status from twitter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

how to access this url https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/firehose.json from twitter4j? I hope this will return all public statuses.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();
System.out.println("Showing home timeline.");
for (Status status : statuses) {
    System.out.println(status.getUser().getName() + ":" +
                       status.getText());
}
```

Comment: yup. this is working. But I don't want my own timeline. I want it to get all public statuses. This [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/firehose) gives a JSON url and I don't know how to access that URL in twitter4j. Could you please help me?

Comment: I'd suggest you to paste a section of the content of the URL in the question. I'm behind a firewall - your link is not opening for me :(

Comment: contents are : Returns all public statuses. Few applications require this level of access. Creative use of a combination of other resources and various access levels can satisfy nearly every application use case.

Resource URL
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/firehose.json                                                                               Example Request
Use the OAuth tool in this page sidebar to generate the OAuth signature for this request.

GET 
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/firehose.json